# AndroidStudio adding two images to a button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and I was wondering is there any way **to add two images to a button and only one of them to be visible(active) at a time**?

Now I am using the following technique:
In my activity I have 4 buttons and to all of them I have register an `View.OnTouchListener` and I manage the events in it like this:

```
private class ButtonOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                clickButton(v);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                unClickButton(v);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                    v.callOnClick();
                }

                break;
        }

        // tell the system that we handled the event but a further processing is required
        return false;
    }

    private void clickButton(View button) {
        switch (button.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonLogin:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_enter_press);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRegister:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_registration_press);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonCheckUpdate:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_update_check_press);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonExit:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_exit_press);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void unClickButton(View button) {
        switch (button.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonLogin:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_enter_idle);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRegister:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_registration_idle);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonCheckUpdate:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_update_check_idle);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonExit:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_main_button_exit_idle);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So in this way I am making a switch in the event to determine which button is clicked and change the appropriate resource. Which means that for each activity I must create a custom class and do the switches in the events.

Could I make something like the following:

```
    private void ClickButton(View button){
        button.setBackgroundResource(button.getResourceImage1);
        }

    private void unClickButton(View button){
        button.setBackgroundResource(button.getResourceImage2);
        }
```

This way I can make a global `OnTouchListener` and just set the images in the xml file for each button and not to worry about any java code.

I tried to switch between `background`/`foreground` images but I couldn't hide the foreground image for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can make a drawable file selector for this purpose
Like this:

button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/activity_main_button_enter_press"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/activity_main_button_enter_press"
    android:state_selected="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/activity_main_button_enter_idle" />
```

And in your java code on click of button:

```
btn.setSelected(!btn.isSelected());
```

And set the selector drawable file to your button:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector.xml"
    android:text="Click_me"/>
```

Comment: Strange, it works only the first time that I press the button. The next time I press it it doesn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, Sorry I didn't clear all my previous code for changing the picture. It works now. This is the answer, thanks! :)

Comment: As I saw I can only create a single `selector` within a xml file. Do you know a way to put all selectors in one file?  @Er.Rohit Sharma

Comment: No, its not possible. You have to create different xml files for each selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [State List Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for each button and implement `android:state_pressed`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/activity_main_button_enter_press"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/activity_main_button_enter_idle" />
</selector>
```